# How to make a batch file move/manage the size of other windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that can move itself or another file around and I honestly have no clue how or even if this can be accomplished.

Comment: [Search for similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+resize+windows), try the solutions, then if something doesn't work edit the question and add the details, or if everything works as is, rejoice, there was no need to ask.

Comment: You can't do that directly with a batch file. But a batch file can call VBScript or any number of other things that _can_ do that. Why does it need to be a batch file?  By move do you mean move to another folder or move the window on the screen? be more specific.

Comment: Batch can't do this natively. Thus is one of only two times I will ever recommend using PowerShell on a question that has the [batch-file] tag.